# FragmentTransaction on a ListView item click listener

Tags: java, android

I am using this code to perform a `FragmentTransaction` when I click on a list view item.

Here is the code:

```
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            android.support.v4.app.Fragment detail = new ProductsPurchasedFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, detail).addToBackStack("back").commit();
        }

        });
```

Note: `main_container` is placed in `MainActivity` class the layout were I want the fragment to be placed.

Here is the XML that I am using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewPurchases"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbarSize="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know if has any relevance but here is the `CustomAdapter` XML file for the `ListView` items:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dispensaryAdressPurchases"
    android:layout_width="300sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dispensaryNamePurchases"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dispensaryNamePurchases"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dispensaryNamePurchases"
    android:layout_width="300sp"
    android:textColor="@color/valet_green"
    android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cityAndStatePurchases"
    android:layout_width="300sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dispensaryAdressPurchases"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dispensaryAdressPurchases"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:ems="10" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dispensaryIDP"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/dispensaryNamePurchases"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem I am encountering here is when I click on one of the `ListView`'s items, it throws:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0800ba
>   (com.example.dragosandrei.greenkinexdorian:id/main_container) for
>   fragment ProductsPurchasedFragment{da5eb68 #3 id=0x7f0800ba}

The list view is placed in a tab fragment that is also placed on a fragment. 
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just like the error says there is no View with that ID.

Comment: You have added container ID to be R.id.main_container but there is no such 
 layout with that id in any of the layout content you added .

Comment: for the change to test just do this 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewPurchases"

Comment: So where you want the Fragment to appear?

Comment: On main_container.

Comment: But there is NO MainContainer??

Comment: Read the notes. main_container is the layout placed on MainActivity class

Comment: Okay you have got it wrong you should define a `View` with id `main_container`!!

Comment: Try it now. I don't know why it disappeared.

Comment: Should I create thet View on main_ container or I just define him to "trick" the program?

Comment: Update my layout with what? How?

Comment: Okay I have answered how! check my answer below if you find any difficulties comment below! @AndreiNechita

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Layout with an ID called `main_container` for your Logic to work. For instance you can add a `FrameLayout` with an id `main_container` in your Activity's Layout!Like this:

Below your `ListView` in XML add this:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/main_container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/listViewPurchases" >
</FrameLayout>
```

That should be inside `RelativeLayout` but after `ListView` if you still find some difficulties comment below!

Comment: Okay lets go slowly because I cant see your pc. Change `wrap_content` in my answer to `500dp` lets try to divide your screen first! Tell me what happens!

Comment: Can we make a skype call to show you exactly what I want to do here? Is more complicate that that.

Comment: I want to replace a whole tabbed fragment with another fragment.

Comment: Now I have got you send me the code! We can not skype due to my network connection kinda very slow. Send me here `johnnnoni@gmail.com`. I want the Activity code and both fragments code!

Comment: Sorry I did not open my email earlier! Just did it now!

Comment: Sent you an email! @AndreiNechita

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I had to get the parentFragment and get the fragment manager form the parent.

```
Fragment ft = getParentFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ft.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();   
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container , new ProductsPurchasedFragment());
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```